# Remove site from DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

My company has a enrollment website that is currently in DotNetNuke.  I've been directed to "strip out nuke from the site" but from everything I've read it is the opposite that the site is in dnn not the other way around.

Has anyone had to migrate a site from dnn and if so can you point me towards some resources or give some insite to get me started?

The site is dnn 5.04

Comment: Are you asking how to get rid of all the content management functionality, and user and role management functionality, as well?

Comment: No they're basically wanting to have a working web app that isn't dependant on dnn.   Their thinking was that the web app exists and DNN is a module that is caled for specific functions but from what I've seen it is the opposite.  Dnn is the framework that the app is built upon which would make pulling out dnn almost impossible short of rebuilding the app on its own.

Comment: @Brian, you hit the nail on the Head.  DNN is a frameowrk on which sites/apps are built.  Stripping out DNN means rebuilding the app.  Modules that were custom written for the site, can probably be converted to "standard" ASP.Net for relatively little effort, but portions of the site that depend on core features or 3rd party modules are going to be a lot more work.

Comment: This begs the question: Why strip out DNN?

Comment: well the short answer is because my boss asked me to look at what it would take.  We've inherited a mishmash of systems all developed on different platforms and they are wanting to eliminate some of the black boxes in the code so we can better respond to changes and problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "enrollment website" sounds more like an application than a static HTML site and if that's the case then just grabbing the rendered HTML isn't going to be the best option as you wouldn't get any of the functionality. My approach would be to first find out why they want it pulled out of DotNetNuke. Perhaps it was poorly implemented and they are blaming DNN when the problem was actually how it was built. DNN may be a good solution and it might be best to convince them to leave it as DNN but improve the implementation.

If you do need to pull an application out of DNN and the enrollment piece was built as a custom module, it should be fairly easy to convert the ascx files of the custom module to normal .net User Controls.

If the Enrollment application was built using a Forms Module of some form, then you will likely need to rebuild it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strip things down to absolute bare bones (HTML, images, JavaScript), you could use a tool that basically copies down an entire website to your local machine, such as [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).

Download the app, give it your DNN website's URL, and it'll spider the entire website, download each page individually, along with any of its images and scripts.  You'll be (theoretically) left with a full website containing all your content pages, which you can edit in a plain text editor.

All the user management, role management, content management, admin only areas, protected content, etc. will not carry over with this method, but that will be the case regardless if you're moving from DNN to a normal static HTML website.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't the answer I was hoping for but certainly was the answer I feared.